# OR condition in Shell Scripting - Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I declare three variables.

```
$1=`ssh <server_1> cat /etc/passswd|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID`
$2=`ssh <server_2> cat /etc/shadow|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID`
$3=`ssh <server_3> cat /etc/passwd}|cut -f -d:|grep -i $CID`
```

The above three variables are created by taking ssh to servers and checking the presence of the IDs which I give as input. If the ID doesn't exist already, the the variable is going to be null.

Now, how do I verify if all the three variables are null. I wanted to use the OR condition specified within an IF.

I tried,

```
if [ -s "$1" -o  -s "$2" -o  -s "$3"];then
echo -$1 $2 $3 "already exist(s)"
```

It didnt work. Please advise.

PS: I have just begun my career in Unix and correct me If am wrong anywhere.

Comment: `-s` tests a *file* for having zero size. Not a string. String emptiness is `-z`.

Comment: Do *not* start arguments to `echo` with a `-` *especially* when the rest of the word isn't under your control. The behaviour is unspecified. Use `printf`.

Comment: There's a stray `}` in the `ssh <server_3>` line.  You can't assign to variables reliably using the `$1=...` notation. If it works, it assigns to the variable whose name is `$1`.  You don't assign to positional parameters like that (use `set -- arg1 arg2 ...`).  You probably need `v1=$(ssh ...)`, etc.

Comment: As for the verify all three are null, what about `if [ -n "$v1$v2$v3" ]; then ...`?  It checks whether the three variables (I'm assuming you renamed them) when concatenated form a non-empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points.

When you assign to a variable, don't use the dollar sign:

```
foo=xxx
```

Variables `$1`, `$2` etc are already used for your command line arguments. Pick other names. But not `$4`please. :-)

When you specify a command for ssh, and it has arguments, it has to be quoted, because the command needs to be a single argument for ssh. In your case use double quotes, as you want variable expansion for `$IID` etc.

Most Unix utils are able to open input files themselves, so you don't need to start your pipeline with `cat`.

```
foo=`ssh <server_1> "cut -f -d: /etc/passwd | grep -e $IID -e $EID"`
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in my question. I had actually declared it as,

```
1=`ssh <server_1> cat /etc/passswd|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID` 
2=`ssh <server_2> cat /etc/shadow|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID` and so on.
```

And I tried it as ,

```
if [ -s "$1" -o  -s "$2" -o  -s "$3"];then
echo -e $1 $2 $3 "already exist(s)"
```

Since I had to Deliver my script today, I used the conventional method of,

```
ssh <server_1> "cat /etc/passswd|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID" > file1
ssh <server_2> "cat /etc/shadow|cut -f -d:|grep -e $IID -e $EID" > file2
ssh <server_3> "cat /etc/passwd|cut -f -d:|grep -ix $CID" > file3

if [ -s file1 -o -s file2 -o -s file3]; then
for i in `cat file1 file2 file3`
do
echo $i "already exists"
done
else
```

And I have now learnt from my first post, that -s to ensure that a file is not empty and -z is to ensure string is empty.